# Correct way of recutting HLS playlist with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm recording a stream on my server and after it finished I need to trim *x* seconds from the beginning of my video. My stream has `master.m3u8` playlist and then 3 sub `index_[0|1|2].m3u8` playlists.

I'm trying different methods, they all seem to generate a result, but nothing as I expect.

For example this :

> ffmpeg -i index_0.m3u8 -ss 30 -strict -2 -hls_time 6 output_0.m3u

Seems to generate the correct nr. of `*.ts` files, but playlist is is only 30s long. Original `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` was set to **6**, now it is **8**, but actual size is a floating **8.3333...**

I'm definitely missing something.

*Update 1:*

OK, so I figured out why my `*.m3u8` file was to small, by default it only loads last few records in the list so setting `-hls_list_size 0` resolved that. Now I need to figure out how to get rid of floating point video sizes.

*Update 2:*

It seems that I need `-hls_flags split_by_time` flag for HLS transmuxer not to ignore my `hls_time` option. Now my output is even closer to correct result, still have that floating point video size problem.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.933333,
output_clip0.ts
#EXTINF:6.033333,
output_clip1.ts
#EXTINF:5.933333,
output_clip2.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
output_clip3.ts
#EXTINF:3.000000,
output_clip3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```